# What's the standard way of getting an Int value from an EditText ? (Android Kotlin/Java)

Tags: android, kotlin

I am now in the process of cleaning my code.
I have an EditText view that receives an input of type "number".
In my code, I use this code to get the value:

```
            val host: Int = binding.serverInputBox.text.toString().toInt()
```

As you may already know, the `EditText` text values are of type `Editable`, and it just seemed like a long reach to translate it twice, first to `String`, then second to `Int`.

My question is: Is this the most efficient way to do it? Or there are better alternatives even slightly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, there is no direct way to that, `Editable` extends `CharSequence`, there is no `method` to convert `CharSequence` to `Int`, you can do manually though like below, which `String.toInt()` method uses under the hood

```
 var value = 0
 editText.text.forEach { 
    if(it !in '0'..'9') throw NumberFormatException("")
    value = value * 10 + (it - '0')
 }
```

**Update**

You can create `extension` function in `CharSequence` for the same

```
fun CharSequence.toInt(): Int{
    var value = 0
    this.forEach {
        if(it !in '0'..'9') throw NumberFormatException("Invalid Input")
        value = value * 10 + (it - '0')
    }
    return value
}
```

Usage without `toString()` method in between

```
val host: Int = binding.serverInputBox.text.toInt()
```